# Hoare's Axiom Scheme Precondition

Tags: hoare-logic

I have a question about determining preconditions for Hoare's Axiom Scheme. For example, if we have `P { x=2 } x==1` and we are trying to determine the precondition, P, could we just set P as false giving us `False { x=2 } x==1`. I've read some of the other posts on this forum about Hoare's Axiom Scheme but am having a hard time wrapping my head around the topic.

Comment: It is not clear what you don't understand or disagree with. $\{\text{false}\}\, x:= 2\, \{x=1\}$ and $\{\text{true}\}\, x:= 2 \,\{x=2\}$ are two correct annotations. What is your question ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can set P to be false.  However, the resulting statement won't be very useful.

Let's back up, and consider how to interpret a statement like `P {x=2} x==2`.  This is saying that for every state of the program that satisfies `P`, if you execute `x=2` in that state, then the state of the program afterwards will satisfy `x==2`.  How useful is this?  Well, the more states that satisfy, the more powerful and useful a statement this is -- the more you have learned.

So, a statement like `true {x=2} x==2` is correct, and also very useful: it works no matter what the prior program state.  It says that, no matter the previous program state, if you execute `x=2`, then the expression `x==2` will hold afterwards.

In contrast, a statement like `false {x=2} x==2` is correct, but not useful.  It is correct, because it claims that for every program state that satisfies `false`, then executing `x=2` will leave you in a program state where `x==2`.  This is [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth), since there are no program states that satisfy `false`.  However, it is not very useful.  There are no program states that satisfy `false`, so there are no program states where this tells you something useful about what will happen if you execute `x=2`.

Now let's move on to the example you gave, of `P {x=2} x==1`.

How about `true {x=2} x==1`?  This is incorrect.  It's not true.  If you start in a program state where, for instance, `x==7`, then this will satisfy `true`, but after executing `x=2`, the condition `x==1` will not be satisfied.  So, that's just a faulty claim.

How about `false {x=2} x==1`?  This is a correct claim.  For the same reasons as explained above, it is vacuously true. However, for the same reasons as explained above, it is not useful: there are no situations where this is a useful claim to know, since there are no program states that satisfy `false`.

---

Generally we look for the [*weakest* precondition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_transformer_semantics).  Here a precondition that is "strong" is one that is restrictive; thus "False" is strong and "True" is weak.  Notice that weak preconditions are one that apply to more prior states, and thus are more useful (can be applied to a larger set of prior states), so the weaker the precondition `P`, the more useful the statement will be.  In other words, the weakest precondition is in some sense the most useful precondition.  "False" is a very strong precondition; while it might be a valid precondition, it is not useful.

Comment: What do you mean "not useful" ? It does prove that the algorithm is not correct.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, Thanks for the feedback!  I've revised my answer to try to elaborate on my reasoning.